# cryptopp base64 trailing 0x0a

Tags: base64, crypto++

I'm using CryptoPP to encode a string "abc", the problem is the encoded base64 string always has a trailing '0x0a'?
here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "crypto/base64.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main() {
string in("abc");

string encoded;

CryptoPP::StringSource ss(
    in,
    true, 
    new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)
    )
);

cout << encoded.length() << endl;// outputs 5, should be 4
cout << encoded;
}
```

the string "abc" should be encoded to "YWJj", but the result is YWJj\n, (\n == 0x0a), and the length is 5 .

Changing the source string doesn't help, any string will be encrypted with a trailing \n
Why is that?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Base64Encoder docs](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_base64_encoder.html), the signature of the constructor is

> ```
> Base64Encoder (BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL,
>                bool insertLineBreaks=true,
>                int maxLineLength=72)
> ```

So you get line breaks by default in your encoded string.  To avoid this, just do:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(
    in,
    true, 
    new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded),
        false
    )
);
```